# Evitar que Overlay afecta a la imagen

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy realizando un pequeño **Overlay** cuando el cursor se posicione en la imagen.

HTML:

```
<div class="item-content GraphicDesign all">
    <div id="icono">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <img src="imgport/Alaz.png" alt="">
</div>
```

La clase principal `item-content` tiene una función en **JQuery** que lo que hace es obtener todas las **url** de las imágenes de las etiquetas **img** de mí **HTML**, cuando le des clic a la imagen, esta se abrirá en otro **div** donde aparece pequeña pero luego al pasar el cursor esta hace un efecto zoom con animation (es como una galería de imágenes).

Ahora estoy intentando colocar una especie de Overlay para que cuando se pase el ratón haga como cubierta en la imagen (estoy hablando antes de que el usuario le de clic a la imagen y se aparezca el otro div con la función JQuery).

**Este código CSS es el del Overlay**

```
#icono {
    position: absolute;
    height: 71%;
    width: 92%;
    z-index: 1
}

#icono::before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(48, 92, 176, 0.46) , rgba(87, 172, 161, 0.62));
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: scale(0);
}
#icono:hover:before {

    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: top;
}
```

Con este código hace el efecto de Overlay pero el problema es que la imagen que esta cubierta por el overlay no se le puede hacer click, y por  lo tanto no puedo hacerle click a la imagen y acceder al otro div donde se muestra la imagen diminuta.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo hacer para que el Overlay no afecte a la imagen? O sea que el efecto del **Hover** se aplique pero que me deje darle clic a la imagen para así ver la otra vista (cuando la imagen aparezca diminuta y se le haga zoom) que es donde tengo la función JQuery.

¿Alguna idea para esto?

**Edit: Estas son las imágenes, a cada imagen se le puede hacer click**

[image: Img]

**Cuando le doy click se accede a otro div, donde esta esa imagen.**

[image: entorno de vista]

Acá se puede apreciar el hover cuando sé esta empezando a expandir, lo de abajo es una etiqueta que la img, cada imagen tiene un etiqueta que lo identifica

[image: Este es el hover completo]

Todo lo azul es el hover que se expande.

Función JQuery:

```
$(function()
        {
            const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
            document.querySelectorAll('.grid .item-content img')
                .forEach((element) =>
                {
                    const url = element.getAttribute('src');
                    element.addEventListener('click', () =>
                    {
                        overlay.classList.add('active');
                        const url2 = document.querySelector('#overlay img')
                            .src = url;
                    });
                });
        }
```

Nota: overlay.classList.add('active'); me ejecuta un flexbox para posicionar la imagen y lo del contenido en la variable url2, me permite invocar un el otro div 
(osea la otra vista)

**Nota:** El overlay es el entorno Zoom, donde ejecuta la función Jquery con la imagen, específicamente el atributo img SRC vacío me permite hacer referencia a las url de la imágenes

```
<section class="overlay" id="overlay">
<div class="img-content">
    <button id="cerrar"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></button>
  <img src="" alt=""> <!-- llamado de imagen -->
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías hacer algo como [esto](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay_no-anim) que he encontrado en w3school, solo tendrías que cambiar el contenido del div que aparece, no se si es lo que quieres pero espero que te sirva.

Comment: Amigo gracias por contestar, acabo de editar mi pregunt, para que puedes ver como es la galería.

Comment: Igualemente es mas o menos lo que quiero hacer pero no da la talla.

Comment: Fijate este [link](https://miketricking.github.io/bootstrap-image-hover/), es de hover sobre imagenes en bootstrap, lo que deberias cambiar de alguno de estos hovers, seria que el tag <a> este en todo el overlay y no solo en el boton que trae, porque en definitiva si el overlay cubre la imagen, el enlace deberia estar puesto sobre el overlay. Ojala te sirva.

Comment: Hola buen dia, el caso es que la imagen no es un enlace <a>, por que lo estoy llamando desde la url, osea me refiero a que a la imagen en si se le hace click y no al hover, por que si le doy click al hover no me acciona lo de la imagen (claro la esta cubriendo).

Comment: Editare nuevamente, para colocar mi función jquery. Otra cosa, no habra una manera de relacionar la clase icono con item content?, lo hago pero me sale la imagen rota.

Comment: Lo que se se me ocurre es hacer que la imagen trabaje conjuntamente con el overlay, osea que al hacer click en el hover despliegue la vista zoom. Estoy confundido.

Comment: Una cuestión lo que necesitas es que ha darle click  te aga la animación de escala  no? . Te dejo este enlace espero que te ayude https://api.jquery.com/toggle/ Es la función toggle de jQuery se podría hacer con JavaScript

Comment: No exactamente, por que eso lo logro con hover. Lo que quiero es que se muestre el fondo azul y que pueda hacerle click a la imagen para visualizar el otro entorno amigo.

Comment: Si tal vez reduzco el overlay, que se vea en la esquina pero seria como llamar al hover pero cuando pase el cursor por la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución puede ser simple si le agregas el **addEventListener** del click en el contenedor **item-content** y no en la imagen.

En tu caso tienes un elemento de clase css llamado **icono** el cual se superpone a la imagen cuando se hace el hover, por lo cual cuando haces el click no te deja acceder al elemento **imagen** que queda debajo ya que los elementos son **hermanos** por el cual el click no es delegado entre ellos dos.

Creo que algo como esto te puede servir.
https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/o3L8azq1/79

**HTML**

```
<!-- Galeria de imagenes -->
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/150/150" />
    <div class="item__description">
      click 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/150/150" />
    <div class="item__description">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/150/150" />
    <div class="item__description">
      click 3
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<!-- Muestra la imagen en una ventana modal -->
<section id="overlay">
  <button id="cerrar">x</button>
  <img id="imagen-overlay" src="" alt="imagen" />
</section>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Variables
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var cerrar = document.getElementById('cerrar');
var imagenOverlay = document.getElementById('imagen-overlay');

// Recorro cada item y habilito el click para mostrar la modal cuando
// se da click en alguno de los items de la galería.
items.forEach(item => item.onclick = (el) => {
  var img = el.currentTarget.childNodes[1];
  var src = img.getAttribute('src');

  overlay.classList.toggle("mostrar");
  imagenOverlay.src = src;
});

// Cierro la ventana modal cuando le doy click al botón cerrar
cerrar.onclick = () => {
  overlay.classList.toggle("mostrar");
};
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

.gallery {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

.item .item__description {
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item:hover .item__description {
  opacity: 1;
}

#overlay {
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeIn 200ms;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#overlay.mostrar {
  display: flex;
}

#cerrar {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

#cerrar:hover {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Si es justo eso lo que quiero, pero tengo una pregunta. Como puedo hacer si en tal caso estoy haciendo la llamada de la imagen pero en otro div. En este momento acabo de colocar el html de la clase (overlay). Lo que hago es llamar a otro div sin imagene para que se pase una referencia.

Comment: Coloque el codigo mas abajo, gracias por contestar!.

Comment: Ahi quedo actualizado el código, dime si así te sirve. Saludos.

Comment: Ok buenas noches, estuve probando el codigo, cuando le doy click a la imagen justo cuando el overlay (la cubierta azul en  mi caso) se muestra, me sale la imagen pero rota.

Comment: Pero me di cuenta de algo, pasa que tu en vez de usar otro div, estas usando un hover a tu misma clase item, pero en mi caso yo tengo una clase icono que me muestra un overlay (azul) sobre mi imagen. Esto lo hago por que no puedo colocarle un fondo decorativo a la imagenes por que se sobreponen, aun colocandole posicion absolute el fondo se muestra pero detras de las imagenes

Comment: Por eso es que coloco esa clase, para poder darle otros estilos y que se me muestra como una especie de hover explandible en las imagenes

Comment: Nuevamente, gracias!